# JavaScript map array using JSON file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dictionary

In JavaScript I have an array of three letter codes and I have a JSON file that has values for each of these codes. I need to map the codes to the corresponding values in the JSON file.
Here's an example:

```
{"Roles" : [
{"code": "cmm", "fullname": "commentator"},
{"code": "cmp", "fullname": "composer"},
{"code": "cnd", "fullname": "conductor"},
{"code": "cng", "fullname": "cinematographer"},
{"code": "cns", "fullname": "censor"},
{"code": "com", "fullname": "compiler"}
]}

var arr = ["cmm", "com", "cng"];
var mappedArray = arr.map( ??? );

//mappedArray now contains: ["commentator", "composer", "cinematographer"]
```

I can't think of a way of solving this that isn't horribly inefficient. Can anyone help?

Comment: You should add your horribly inefficient code to your question.

Comment: I think I understood this wrong. Can you please write your expected output

Comment: How much data are you working with? Assuming you don't have a vast number of roles (thousands+), it's unlikely efficiency is worth spending much, if any, time on.

Comment: Why is `composer` in your output? You meant `compiler`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way would still be to use a [for/loop](https://hackernoon.com/3-javascript-performance-mistakes-you-should-stop-doing-ebf84b9de951):

```js
const data = {"Roles" : [{"code": "cmm", "fullname": "commentator"},{"code": "cmp", "fullname": "composer"},{"code": "cnd", "fullname": "conductor"},{"code": "cng", "fullname": "cinematographer"},{"code": "cns", "fullname": "censor"},{"code": "com", "fullname": "compiler"}]};
var arr = ["cmm", "com", "cng"];

const out = [];
for (let i = 0; i < data.Roles.length; i++) {
  const el = data.Roles[i];
  if (arr.indexOf(el.code) > -1) out.push(el.fullname);
}

console.log(out);
```

Using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is a little more functional/neater but won't be as efficient. You can pull out the data you want without the round trip of using `filter` *then* `map`.

```js
const data = {"Roles" : [{"code": "cmm", "fullname": "commentator"},{"code": "cmp", "fullname": "composer"},{"code": "cnd", "fullname": "conductor"},{"code": "cng", "fullname": "cinematographer"},{"code": "cns", "fullname": "censor"},{"code": "com", "fullname": "compiler"}]};
var arr = ["cmm", "com", "cng"];

var out = data.Roles.reduce((acc, c) => {
  if (arr.includes(c.code)) acc.push(c.fullname);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using  [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var obj = {"Roles" : [
{"code": "cmm", "fullname": "commentator"},
{"code": "cmp", "fullname": "composer"},
{"code": "cnd", "fullname": "conductor"},
{"code": "cng", "fullname": "cinematographer"},
{"code": "cns", "fullname": "censor"},
{"code": "com", "fullname": "compiler"}
]}

var arr = ["cmm", "com", "cng"];

var mappedArray = obj["Roles"].filter(d => arr.includes(d.code))

console.log('Filtered Array', mappedArray)

console.log('Result', mappedArray.map(({fullname}) => fullname))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first filter the array and then map it to get the required values..
you can try this

```
let result1 = obj["Roles"].filter(function(item) { return arr.includes(item.code)}).map(filteredObj => filteredObj.fullname);
```